# d3js globe disable Y-axis drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm making a globe using d3js and I need to disable y-axis drag in the globe. I have no Idea to do this and I really need help. I think this is the code for dragging,

```
  var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

var suppressClick = false;

var zoom = d3.geo.zoom()
    .projection(projection)
    .scaleExtent([projection.scale() * .7, projection.scale() * 10])
    .on("zoomstart", function() {
      // TODO inertial drag   
      if (d3.event.sourceEvent) svg.selectAll("path").classed("focus", false);  

    })
    .on("zoom", function() {        
        if (d3.event.sourceEvent) d3.event.sourceEvent.preventDefault();
        svg.classed("zooming", true).call(redraw);

        //svg.call(redraw);
        suppressClick = true;
    })
    .on("zoomend", function() {
      svg.classed("zooming", false);
      // TODO inertial drag
    });

        var svg = d3.select("#globe").append("svg").attr("width",   width).attr("height", height);

        var pathG = svg.append("g").attr('class','globe middle').call(zoom);
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: If it is dragging, should you be using d3.drag?